# Swift+xcode - auto layout high as much as needed

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

I am new to swift and so I am not familiar with auto layout. I have an image. on the right of the image is a label. The distance to the right label should be 8. Also I have a label under the image. Here the distance should also be 8.

My hope was that the picture is doing its size now automatically. But on the picture you can see that it tells me that there is a problem with constraints. Probably because I dont told the image to always make the picture in the view as wide as possible and than look how high it needs to be. But I also dont know how do add a constraint like this. Can you help me?

[image: wrong constraint picture]

Constraints on image top left:

```
scissor.top = topMargin (so 0 to top)
scissor.leading = leadingMargin (so 0 to left)
```

constraint between scissor and label on bottom:

```
label.top =scissor.bottom + 8 (so distance of 8 between them)
```

constraints of label on bottom:

```
label.bottom = bottomMargin (distance of 0 to bottom)
label.leading = leading.Margin (so dostance of 0 to the left)
```

constraint between label on right and scissor:

```
articleLable.leading = scissor.trailing + 8 (so distance of 8)
```

constraint of label on right:

```
articleLable.top = topMargin
articleLable.trailing = trailingMargin
```

Comment: What's the height/width of the UIImageView? should it be static or dynamic based on size screen?

Comment: @AhmadF dynamic based on size screen and the high automatically to fit

Comment: Can you add all of the constraints you have on your image (and possibly the labels)?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry added constraints

Comment: @Sonius What's the constraint error then? What does it say you need?

Comment: AutoLayout for each view (except buttons and labels just need position) need size (width and height ) and position ( x and y) so must add size for your image .

Comment: You should also set priorities. I guess a higher content compression resistance for your labels or something that would ensure minimum size for bottom & right sides...

Answer (score 0):

You need to constrain the imageView, because x-Code does not know what 'as wide as possible' means. 
I assume you mean that the left side of the imageView and the Cell's left side are identical and the top side of the imageView and the Cell are identical. 
Adding these two constraints should fix the issue.

Comment: I have the two constraints already:

scissor.top = topMargin (so 0 to top)
scissor.leading = leadingMargin (so 0 to left)

Answer (score 0):

you can click on red icon like image for detail
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmp3l.png)